# Do functions get the latest state value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function inside of my functional component that uses a value saved in state. However, when it is called, it has the original value in state, not the updated value. When I look at my component in Chrome React Dev Tools, I see that the updated value is stored in state. Aren't functions supposed to get the latest state value in React? I didn't think I'd have to wrap my functions in a useEffect every time some value in state they depend on changes. Why is this happening?

```
const Editor = (props) => {
  const [template, setTemplate] = useState(null);
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
   if (props.templateId) {
     getTemplate(props.templateId));
   }
  },[]);

  const getTemplate = (templateId) => {
    {...make API to get template...}
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.template) setTemplate(response.template);
    });
  }

  /* THIS FUNCTION SAYS TEMPLATE IS ALWAYS NULL */
  const sendClick = async () => {
    if (template) {
      await updateTemplate();
    } else {
      await initializeTemplate();
    }
    setOpenDialog(true);
  };

}
```

UPDATE: I figured out the issue. The sendClick function is being used inside an object that I have in state. When that object is created, it creates a version of the sendClick function based on the state at that time. I realized I needed to refactor my code so that the function is not stored within my object in state so that the function will always have the latest state values.

Comment: It looks like it should be: `setTemplate(response.template)`

Comment: Also, it should probably be `getTemplate(props.template)` in the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: You shouldn't put functions in the state data, it's a bad practice with React.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I had no idea that putting functions in state data was bad. Thank you for telling me this! Looks like I have some refactoring to do!

Comment: There are some exceptions, like when dealing with the new context API, where you'll have to put the setter function in the state somewhere to trigger re-renders, etc. But most of the time, you should try to avoid functions, class instances, etc in the state directly and instead use props to pass functions around.

Answer (score -2):

Please correct the code there its `setTemplate(template));` not `getTemplate(template));`
I'm guessing that you have that right in the source code... if Yes then,

You have got into a trap that all developers new to React fall into.

This code is betraying you ...

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (props.template) {
     setTemplate(template)); // Mentioned as getTemplate(template));
   }
  },[]); // Here is where you make the mistake
```

The second argument you pass to the `useEffect` is called as *Dependencies*. Meaning if your `useEffect` is dependent on any state or any variable or function, Ii should be pass as the second argument inside the `[]`. By now you should have got the answer.

Clearly, your `useEffect` is dependent on `template`. You should pass that inside the `[]`.

So the code will be : -

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (props.template) {
     setTemplate(template)); // Mentioned as getTemplate(template));
   }
  },[template]);
```

Now React will automatically run the function every time the value of `template` changes therefore, updates `template`.

For more information about `useEffect` ...

[Refer React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

[Refer the `useEffect` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

Comment: If this answer is **Useful** please mark it as the _Accepted Answer_